# I want to provide the distance traveled by boaters on a river using mapping software like google maps

Tags: google-maps, maps

Apparently there is no way in google maps to identify a river except by getting the color of the pixel.  This breaks whenever there is a bridge.  Is there a maw to measure distance along a river without building my own gis polygons for every river segment I want to use?

Comment: Could you perhaps look for the name of the bridge?  It might not work for every single case though.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried [NASA Worldwind](http://worldwind.arc.nasa.gov/java/)? Although Google Maps is popular and easy to use, it is more useful for road map data. The NASA Worldwind SDK is fairly easy to understand and provides a range of data related to the earth including elevation data.